# How to i split String by new line and by ";" and then fetchall as row

Tags: php, split, fetchall

I have txt file which looks like

```
Stefan;Mihajlovic;2;3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2;100
Milutin;Milankovic;1;2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 89;1000
```

I managed to split it by new line using code below

```
$array = file('test.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    var_dump($array);
```

Output is this:

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> string(82) "Stefan;Mihajlovic;2;3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2;100" 
[1]=> string(82) "Milutin;Milankovic;1;2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 89;1000" 
}
```

What I need now is to split every array by ";" and fetch all as a row.
Honestly, I started learning PHP a few days ago so I have no idea how to do it. 
Any help is appreciated

UPDATE
Sorry i forgot to mention that i need to do it dynamically since new lines will be added every day.

Comment: PHP has a useful built-in function called [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), which would allow you to set the separator argument as a semi-colon (`;`)... the PHP Docs page that I've linked shows you how to use it

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `explode()` function to create array from string by ;

```
$newArray = array( 
  "Stefan;Mihajlovic;2;3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2;100",
  "Milutin;Milankovic;1;2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 89;1000" 
);
foreach($newArray as $arr) {
   print_r(explode(";",$arr));
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Stefan
    [1] => Mihajlovic
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2
    [4] => 100
)

Array
(
    [0] => Milutin
    [1] => Milankovic
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 89
    [4] => 1000
)
```

Comment: Yea its doing what i need. Thxs

Answer (score 1):

[Use explode function.](https://eval.in/590743)

```
$a = "Stefan;Mihajlovic;2;3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2;100";
$b = explode(";",$a);
var_dump($b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this something like that you want to do ?

```
$myArrayRow = $tab[0];
$explodeArray = explode(";", $arraySplit);

echo $explodeArray[0] // Stefan
echo $explodeArray[1] // Mihajlovic
```

Check this link : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

If I got what you want to do. You might try the explode function:
for example:

```
$myString = "Stefan;Mihajlovic;2;3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2;100";
$myArray = explode(';', $myString);
print_r($myArray);
```

you can try the code in this playground: http://www.tehplayground.com/#j3sy2ItTZ